# Get the Unread mail count in iPhone

Tags: iphone, email, imap, pop3

I want to get the unread mail count of the mail i configured in my Mail App through my App.

If not can i set my own IMAP/POP3 setup configuration and access the mail server i configured and get the Unread mail count. If so point me in the direction where i can start coding for setting up mail server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wouldn't be very cool if random apps could get at your email login/password, now would it? There is no API for getting the unread count.

Your only option is to implement an IMAP/POP3 client in your app, and have the user enter their login / password again in your app.

If you're going that route, try searching GitHub for [IMAP/POP3 clients](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=Objective-C&q=IMAP&repo=&langOverride=&x=18&y=14&start_value=1).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get the unread mail count through your app. You can set up your own configuration.

(Ref. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mailroom-gmail-google-apps/id355023563?mt=8)